# Getting error while Regenerate Application AccessToken using Curl command in wso2 API manager 1.8.0

Tags: curl, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to Regenerate Application access token using Curl Command. I have installed wso2 1.8.0 version. When I tried to fire below command I am getting

```
{"error" : true, "message" : "Error occurred while executing the action generateApplicationKey"}
```

---

Command :

```
curl -X POST -b cookies http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag -d 'action=generateApplicationKey&application=test&keytype=PRODUCTION&callbackUrl=&authorizedDomains=ALL&validityTime=360000'
```

Please help. where is the issue?

Stack trace in wso2carbon.log :

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-12-24 13:47:51,378] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject} -  Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:test {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Could not execute Workflow
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:1746)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:34)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_getApplicationKey(APIStoreHostObject.java:692)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor130.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c3._c_anonymous_2(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag:34)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c3.call(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0._c_anonymous_8(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag:29)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0.call(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag:155)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag:3)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.exec(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error occured when updating the status of the Application creation process
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:79)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:52)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:1742)
        ... 62 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while creating an Application Registration Entry for Application : test
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.handleException(ApiMgtDAO.java:5832)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.createApplicationRegistrationEntry(ApiMgtDAO.java:284)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:74)
        ... 64 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "CONSTRAINT_INDEX_F9 ON PUBLIC.AM_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION(SUBSCRIBER_ID, APP_ID, TOKEN_TYPE)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO  AM_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION (SUBSCRIBER_ID,WF_REF,APP_ID,TOKEN_TYPE,ALLOWED_DOMAINS,VALIDITY_PERIOD)   VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?) [23001-140]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
        at org.h2.index.BaseIndex.getDuplicateKeyException(BaseIndex.java:157)
        at org.h2.index.PageBtree.find(PageBtree.java:121)
        at org.h2.index.PageBtreeLeaf.addRow(PageBtreeLeaf.java:138)
        at org.h2.index.PageBtreeLeaf.addRowTry(PageBtreeLeaf.java:93)
        at org.h2.index.PageBtreeIndex.addRow(PageBtreeIndex.java:90)
        at org.h2.index.PageBtreeIndex.add(PageBtreeIndex.java:81)
        at org.h2.table.RegularTable.addRow(RegularTable.java:116)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:120)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:82)
        at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:70)
        at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:199)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:179)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.createApplicationRegistrationEntry(ApiMgtDAO.java:267)
        ... 65 more
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-12-24 13:47:51,383] ERROR {JAGGERY.site.blocks.subscription.subscription-add.ajax.subscription-add:jag} -  org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:test {JAGGERY.site.blocks.subscription.subscription-add.ajax.subscription-add:jag}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have generated access token and consumer key and secret once, you can use them with [token api](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Token+API) to regenerate access token. It is not possible to regenerate access key using the curl you specified because it is for generate application keys as the action specified, not for regenerate.

As a summary of how you can regenerate access token using generated consumer key and secret of first curl request you had

`curl -X POST -b cookies http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag -d 'action=generateApplicationKey&application=test&keytype=PRODUCTION&callbackUrl=&authorizedDomains=ALL&validityTime=360000'`

is below steps.

1. Create the base64 encoded token using generated consumer key and secret after putting them in following format

`<consumer_key>:<consumer_secret>`

2. Create this call

`curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>" -H "Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded token in step 1>, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token`

This will produce an access token and an refresh token.

3. You can use the refresh token generated in step 2 to regenerate the access token as in below call

`curl -k -d "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=<retoken>&scope=PRODUCTION" -H "Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded token in step 1>, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token`

Comment: Hi Lakshman, Thanks for the quick response. By using above steps I am able to renew access token but why same is not reflected in Access token session of Store UI subscription page. I can regenerate application token using regenerate button present in Store UI which shows newly generated application access token but if we will generate through token API, it is not being reflected on Store UI.

Comment: @Pabitra: API store is not designed in that way. Anyway you should be able to use the access token generated via UI and via curl command.

Comment: If the answer is worked for you,don't hesitate to mark it answer.